# How to substr version numbers string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have strings with version numbers like:

```
"1.4.2.57"
"8.4.3"
"3.12.0.25"
```

I only need the first 3 numbers, I was going to use substr, but if the numbers are > 9 the substr will fail.

How can I extract x.x.x from strings like (x.x - x.x.x - x.x.x.x) where x is = [0-99]

Comment: `^(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)` should do it, you'll have to translate that to javascript regex though. You'll have the first 3 digits with any delimiters in your first three capture groups, you can change \D+ to (?:\s|-|\.)+ if you want to specify .,-, and space as your only valid delimiters with none capturing groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var t = [
    "1.4.2.57",
    "8.4.3",
    "3.12.0.25"
    ];
for (var v = 0; v < t.length; v++){
    var ver = t[v].split('.');
    alert(ver.slice(0,3).join('.'));
}
```

Split by `.`, then slice to get only first 3 digits (in this case elements, since they were split to an array), then rejoin with `.` again.

Comment: Cool, it even works when the version is like "1.5", I though he slice would show an error but it doesn't.

Comment: @riviraz: Correct, slice will silently grab as much as it can, leaving you with only the desired portions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var no_periods = string.replace('.', '');
var new_string = no_periods.substr(0,2);
```

will get rid of all the periods and then just get the first three numbers, is that what you wanted?